# domain redirect to a page and rewrite url of landing to keep orgin domain

Tags: wordpress, .htaccess, redirect, url-rewriting

this it might be easy but I'm not sure how to achieve it (nor if it's actually possible..)

I've made a page in wordpress, with a custom template design, and not linked with the rest of the website, so it's a landing page which actually has nothing to spare with the base website.

I've bought a domain and redirected with a 301 to this page (to pass seo from that page as well).

the problem is that now I'd like to have the url of that page rewritten in order to be the same of the one I've bought, so when landing in that page, viewers won't notice that they are in another domain.

basically I want that a domain like this

my-new-domain.com

which redirects to this page (I've done this)

maindomain.com/landing-page/

and once you're there, the url displayed is:

my-new-domain.com

the page is wordpress, so I need it to keep passing the variables while the url is rewritten.
but I don't need it to handle sub-pages, as the page is a single landing page.

can I do this with an htaccess rule? and if yes, could you please tell me how this rule should ne written?

Thanx to anyone who'll help!
Andrea

Answer (score 0):

You could use [mod_rewrite](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_rewrite.html) for this

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} my-new-domein.com [NC]
RewriteRule ^ /landing-page [L]
```

The first rule is the condition, so if the domein (http host) matches your domein the second line get executed, [NC] means no case, so my-new-domain.com and MY-NEW-DOMAIN.com both work

The second rule has 3 parts

```
^
```

as another condition (always matches)

```
/landing-page
```

that's the page which is passed to wordpress

```
[L]
```

means this is the last rule to be executed, handy when multiple rewrite rules at in the .htacess

**Edit:**

In addition, if you want mydomain.com/landing-page to show it's content but with my-new-domain.com in the url bar use the following to redirect to my-new-domain.com

```
Redirect 302 /landing-page http://my-new-domain.com
```

Comment: Hi Xeli! Thank you very much! Just to avoid mistakes, where should I add this htaccess file? wordpress main folder? new theme folder? I don't want to override other htaccess rules, like wordpress pretty permalinks..

Comment: I'd add it in the main .htaccess file, probably in de same dir as the index.php

Comment: I've added it to the root htaccess file but is not working.. looking at the code I have a doubt. I do need that when on the page main-domain.com/landing-page/ the url is rewritten and displays my-new-domain.com, not the other way round. is that code correct to do this?

Comment: just to be even more clear: I don't need to redirect the new domain to that page, I've done this. I'd like to have the my-new-domain.com written on the url bar, while you are actually viewing the page main-domain.com/landing-page/

Comment: This piece of code will show you the content of domain.com/landing-page, when you type new-domain.com in the browser. Is that what you want?

Comment: no sorry.. I can do that from the admin panel of the domain. I want that when you go to the page main-domain.com/landing-page, you see its content, but the url displayed on the url bar is: my-new-domain.com is this possible?

Comment: I don't want to bother you, but can you please tell me just if what I am looking for is actually possible or it's nonsense? I mean, is it possible to display the content of a page, but have a different domain url written on the browser's url bar?

Comment: Well it's possible, but what I would do is redirect from domain.com/landing-page to my-new-domain.com and then use the above htaccess to show the correct content, see my edit in the answer

Comment: Thanx! do I have to add those both into the same htaccess file on main-domain.com? I'm very ignorant about this things, but I am wondering if this won't create an infinite loop with one page redirecting to the other..

Comment: I've added the redirect rule below the other rewrite rule and the page crashes and tells there is an error: "the page isn't redirecting properly"

Comment: I've updated it, should work now. But I wouldn't recommend it this way, I'd use the first htaccess rule and just change your links to my-new-domain.com

Comment: yes, I know that redirect 302 is not passing info for SEO.. so I appreciate there is no way to achieve what I need.. :( thank you for your help anyway!

Comment: if you use 301 you'll not use any page rank for seo though

Comment: sorry I was not clear, I meant that with 302 google won't read the content of the original page but only the title and meta of the domain (new-domain.com) which redirect to the page. with 301 the domain new-domain.com basically won't exist for google, but following it, google will read the content of the landing page and indicize all the keywords in the content.